# Can a LARGE function ignore returning a value of zero and move to the next largest (which may be negative?)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a function in cell P25:

```
=LARGE(D:D,8)
```

This would find, as anticipated, the eighth largest number. However, in this case I am returning zero (because some cells can have a zero value) and zero just happens to be the eighth largest number in this case.

I would, for all of the LARGE functions, ignore any zero value and print the next highest instead. In this case, the next highest would be a negative number. But also, this number is more valuable than zero as this is a product with some stock. All zero values are products that are completely removed from stock but I do not want them removed from the list as they're still important.

My cell adjacent looks for that "LARGE" number in P25 and prints the product name.

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(LARGE(D:D,8),D:D,0))
```

So when P25 finds a negative number, I will need O25 to find the cell that has that value and print the respective product.

TIA.

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: `=AGGREGATE(14,7,D:D/(--D:D<>0),8)`  But you should probably limit the range to just the dataset, full column references will be slower.

Comment: Office 2019. 

@ScottCraner - how do I get the Index match to work with the Aggregate? This works nicely to find the next highest but I can't seem to use the aggregate in the "MATCH" as well.

Comment: `=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(AGGREGATE(14,7,D:D/(--D:D<>0),8),D:D,0))`

Comment: @ScottCraner - thank you. That works a treat. You know how you said limit to the dataset, I agree with you, but my dataset constantly changes - how do I make sure that the D:D actually picks up the dataset without using D:D? Is there a dynamic trick? Though, a few seconds isn't a problem. If it turned to minutes I can see that being an issue.

Comment: Re _how do I make sure that the D:D actually picks up the dataset without using D:D?_  convert your raw data to a table and use [Structured References](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e)

Comment: @ScottCraner Is the -- really necessary? i tried it without, and can't see a difference